# Link a Headerfile without c file

Tags: c, makefile

I want to link a headerfile which has no corresponding c-file.

How can I do that this is my current Makefile.

```
CC=powerpc-linux-gcc

LIBS = libdrmko.o libdrm.o libs3gko.o

C_SRC = main.c lstLib.c vxTypes.h

C_OBJ = main.o lstLib.o vxTypes.o

graphics_test: $(LIBS) $(C_OBJ)
    $(CC) -o graphics_test $(LIBS) $(C_OBJ)
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not link header files, you include them in your relevant C files:

```
#include "myheader.h"
```

See [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html).

Answer (score 1):

Header files are normally `#include`'d (similar to `#include <stdio.h>`). If the header file only contains prototypes, but not actual implementation, whatever you do you will end up with compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want to get some header files into your project that are **not** in your .c files as `#include`s. 
If your .h files are in a directory appart from the source you can include it with:

```
CFLAGS=-I/directory/to/add
```

and you'll pick up all the .h files in there.